# SetUp() and TearDown() Methods in DalekJs

Tags: dalekjs

Is there a simple way to add a setUp() and/or a tearDown() Method to every DalekJs test?

For example:
I want to resize my browserwindow before and after every test.

Edit:

I played with it around over the weekend and came up with this, it is the easiest solution that i came up with.

`test.open(url);

setUp(test);

test.assert.exists('#logo', 'Logo exists');

tearDown(test);

test.done();`

`function setUp(test) {

test.resize({width:1280, height: 1024})

/*...*/

}`

`function tearDown(test) {

test.resize({width:1280, height: 1024})

}`

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow! you'll get better answers if you give more information about what you are trying to do... i.e. script modifying the tests, in-place modification, etc.

Comment: For now, this is the only possibility. I tried to implement generic Mocha style methods, but the current architecture prevents me from doing so. We are doing a big "throw away nearly everything" which will be finished in probably a month or so. Then  we will have proper methods up & running.

Comment: Ooh how's the "big throwaway everything" going, Sebastian? :)

Comment: @SebastianGolasch A question I just asked [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22446547/how-do-i-do-automating-ember-testing-with-dalek-setup-teardown-of-specific-embe) relates quite a bit to this.